# converting csv to json using .net and sending json data to iothub

Tags: c#, json, linq, csv

I am trying to convert csv data into json data format.

I wrote code as below. How to convert below data as json format data

```
string csvData = File.ReadAllText(csvPath);
```

//Execute a loop over the rows.

```
foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n'))
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
    {
        dt.Rows.Add();
        int i = 0;
        //Execute a loop over the columns.  
        foreach (string cell in row.Split(','))
        {
            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell;
            Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    var telemetryDataPoint = row;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a csv file to json using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824165/converting-a-csv-file-to-json-using-c-sharp)

Comment: CSV text files come with so many questions. If you have Excel, go Data»Get External Data»From Text and select a text file. Run through the Text Import Wizard. You should have an answer to every question and put that knowledge into code, as applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n'))
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
  {
    string jsonString = new 
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(row); //Per row
    dt.Rows.Add();
    int i = 0;
    //Execute a loop over the columns.  
    foreach (string cell in row.Split(','))
    {
      dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell;
      Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i]);
      i++;
    }
  }
  var telemetryDataPoint = row;
}
```

OR

```
// All at once
var data = (from row in csvData.Split('\n')
            select row.Split(',')).ToList();
string jsonString = new 
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data);
```